# WebSockets can't establish connection to server

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, websocket

I'm running the simple Echo example of WebSockets but it doesn't seem to establish a connection. This is happening on Windows 7, Eclipse, and Tomcat.

The error messages in firefox are:

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://my_ip_address:8080/websockets/echo"
```

and

```
Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at ws://my_ip_address:8080/websockets/echo.
```

What am I missing? Is there some configuration I need to set up?

The jars I have in the build path are `javax.annotation_1.0.jar and websocket-api-0.2.jar`

The code I'm running:

```
package org.javaee.glassfishwebsocket;
import org.glassfish.websocket.api.annotations.WebSocket;
import org.glassfish.websocket.api.annotations.WebSocketMessage;

@WebSocket(path="/echo")
public class EchoBean {
    @WebSocketMessage
    public String echo(String message) {
        System.out.println("##################### Message received");
        return message + " (from your server)";
    }     
}
```

This is index.jsp:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
</head>

<body>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>WebSocket Echo Client</title>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

        console.log("trying to connect");

        var wsUri = "ws://my_ip_address:8080/websockets/echo";
        console.log("wsUri = ");
        console.log(wsUri);
        var websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri);
        console.log("websocket = " );
        console.log(websocket);
        websocket.onopen = function(evt) { onOpen(evt) };
        websocket.onmessage = function(evt) { onMessage(evt) };
        websocket.onerror = function(evt) { onError(evt) };

        function init() {
            console.log("init called");
            output = document.getElementById("output");
        }

        function send_echo() {
            console.log("sending_echo with " + textID.value);
            websocket.send(textID.value);
            writeToScreen("SENT: " + textID.value);
        }

        function onOpen(evt) {
            console.log("onOpen");
            writeToScreen("CONNECTED");
        }

        function onMessage(evt) {
            console.log("onMessage");
            writeToScreen("RECEIVED: " + evt.data);
        }

        function onError(evt) {
            console.log("onError");
            writeToScreen('<span style="color: red;">ERROR:</span> ' + evt.data);
        }

        function writeToScreen(message) {
            var pre = document.createElement("p");
            pre.style.wordWrap = "break-word";
            pre.innerHTML = message;
            output.appendChild(pre);
        }

        window.addEventListener("load", init, false);
    </script>

    <h2 style="text-align: center;">WebSocket Echo Client</h2>
    <div style="text-align: center;"><img style=" width: 64px; height: 64px;" alt=""src="HTML5_Logo_512.png"></div>
    <br></br>
    <div style="text-align: center;">
        <form action=""> 
            <input onclick="send_echo()" value="Press me" type="button"> 
            <input id="textID" name="message" value="Hello WebSocket!" type="text"><br>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="output"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is your server-side script actually running on the server when you try to connect from the client?

Comment: I guess it's a good question. It's published on tomcat, and tomcat is running. So I'm assuming it's accessible. Is there a way to test this?

Comment: I tried this uri, var wsUri = "wss://echo.websocket.org/echo"; and it works, so the problem is indeed with the server. It seems like the connection is never established, and onOpen is never called. But how do you debug it? I'm using my actual ip address, but it's not a fixed one. I have wi-fi network with two computers, so I guess the ip is going through my dLink.

Comment: The server-side script has to be running before you can actually connect to it. In other words, you need to execute the server-side script from (likely) your server command line to set up the initial socket, and have it sit there all the time, constantly listening for socket connection requests from clients. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, it does. I guess it's my first real client server application (I did plenty of web apps, almost always through tomcat.) So, do you have a code sample? How do I associate my EchoBeen (the code is above) with the server?